# iterate through array of objects and change apperence of another array inside

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, parsing, mapping

How can i edit an array inside an object?
My array contains a string, but i wanted the string to be split up via **.split("")** or another method.
This is how it looks at the moment:

```
line1_x = [
{"id": 1, "topic_no": 451, "keywords": ["[Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3]"] },
{"id": 2, "topic_no": 452, "keywords": ["[Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3]"] },
{"id": 3, "topic_no": 453, "keywords": ["[Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3]"] }
]
```

In this case, the brackets are part of the string. I would remove them via .replaceAll() or regex, i guess?
What i would like to archieve is following:

```
line1_x = [
{"id": 1, "topic_no": 451, "keywords": ["Keyword1", "Keyword2", "Keyword3"] },
{"id": 2, "topic_no": 452, "keywords": ["Keyword1", "Keyword2", "Keyword3"] },
{"id": 3, "topic_no": 453, "keywords": ["Keyword1", "Keyword2", "Keyword3"] }
]
```

I assume i need to iterate through the line1_x via a normal loop and use the **.split("")** method?

Comment: Please post your complete string value, You can use `JSON.parse(text);'

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+split+strings+inside+object+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: @SudiptoBhattacharya No. The ["A,B,C"] is not valid JSON

Comment: What if Instead of Keyword1, you have something with a comma or a double quote? How would it look then? These things are better fixed at the source. How did you get that structure in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose a regex solution:

```
(?!\s)[^\[\],]+?(?=\s*[\],])
```

> Matching everything but not `,`, `[` or `]` that does not start with a whitespace, and end with `]` or `,`.

```js
const line1_x = [
  {"id": 1, "topic_no": 451, "keywords": ["[Hello world,Back/front end, full-stack!]"] },
  {"id": 2, "topic_no": 452, "keywords": ["[Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3!]"] },
  {"id": 3, "topic_no": 453, "keywords": ["[Keyword1,Keyword2, Some Keyword3 ]"] }
];

const output = line1_x.map(({ keywords, ...rest }) => ({ 
  ...rest,
  keywords: keywords[0].match(/(?!\s)[^\[\],]+?(?=\s*[\],])/g)
}));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: doesnt capture `!` in a keyword

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev updated according to your added information.

Answer (score 0):

Trim the brackets and split with a comma plus a space.
The question implies modifying the array in-place:

```js
line1_x.forEach(item => item.keywords = item.keywords[0].slice(1, -1).split(', '));

console.log(line1_x);
```

```html
<script>
const line1_x = [
{"id": 1, "topic_no": 451, "keywords": ["[Hello world!, Keyword2, Keyword3]"] },
{"id": 2, "topic_no": 452, "keywords": ["[Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3]"] },
{"id": 3, "topic_no": 453, "keywords": ["[Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3]"] }
]
</script>
```

And the benchmark:

[image]

```html
<script benchmark data-count="300000">
const line1_x = [
  {"id": 1, "topic_no": 451, "keywords": ["[Hello world!, Keyword2, Keyword3]"] },
  {"id": 2, "topic_no": 452, "keywords": ["[Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3]"] },
  {"id": 3, "topic_no": 453, "keywords": ["[Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3]"] }
];

// @benchmark Peter
line1_x.map(({ keywords, ...other }) => ({
  ...other,
  keywords: Array
    .from(
      keywords
        .at(0)
        .matchAll(/[[,]\s*(?<keyword>[^,\]]+)/g)
    )
    .map(({ groups: { keyword } }) => keyword.trim())
}));

// @benchmark Hao Wu
line1_x.map(({ keywords, ...rest }) => ({ 
  ...rest,
  keywords: keywords[0].match(/(?!\s)[^\[\],]+?(?=\s*[\],])/g)
}));

// @benchmark Thomas
{
const line = [
  {"id": 1, "topic_no": 451, "keywords": ["[Hello world!, Keyword2, Keyword3]"] },
  {"id": 2, "topic_no": 452, "keywords": ["[Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3]"] },
  {"id": 3, "topic_no": 453, "keywords": ["[Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3]"] }
];

line.map(row => {
    row.keywords = row.keywords[0].replaceAll(/[\[\]']+/g, "").split(", ");
    return row;
  });
}
 

// @benchmark Alexander
{
const line1_x = [
  {"id": 1, "topic_no": 451, "keywords": ["[Hello world!, Keyword2, Keyword3]"] },
  {"id": 2, "topic_no": 452, "keywords": ["[Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3]"] },
  {"id": 3, "topic_no": 453, "keywords": ["[Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3]"] }
];
line1_x.forEach(item => item.keywords = item.keywords[0].slice(1, -1).split(', '));
line1_x;
}
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: Interesting use of the `\w+` regex keyword, also appreciate for the benchmark, but won't work with non alphanumeric keywords like: 1!2, multiple keywords like: Hello world, and stuff like: Front/Back, full-stack

Comment: @ThomasZimmermann threw away the regex, splitting works fine, updated the benchmark

Answer (score 0):

The main task is a regex based parsing of the OP's object's `keywords` values. A possible regex like ... [`/[[,]\s*(?<keyword>[^,\]]+)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/CPAFnS/1) ... might utilize [named capturing groups](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#named-groups).

The overall task then is [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)ping the OP's data-structure where each data-item will be recreated as partial shallow copy via [destructuring and rest property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#rest_property) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). Each new item also gets assigned the newly computed expected `keywords` array-value as result of [matching all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) grouped `keyword` occurrences.

```js
console.log(
  [
    { "id": 1, "topic_no": 451, "keywords": ["[Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3]"] },
    { "id": 2, "topic_no": 452, "keywords": ["[Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3]"] },
    { "id": 3, "topic_no": 453, "keywords": ["[Keyword1,Keyword2, Some Keyword3 ]"] },
  ]
  .map(({ keywords, ...other }) => ({
    ...other,
    keywords: Array
      .from(
        keywords
          .at(0)
          // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/CPAFnS/1]
          .matchAll(/[[,]\s*(?<keyword>[^,\]]+)/g)
      )
      .map(({ groups: { keyword } }) => keyword.trim())
  }))
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the working example:**

```js
let line1_x = [
  { id: 1, topic_no: 451, keywords: ["[Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3]"] },
  { id: 2, topic_no: 452, keywords: ["[Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3]"] },
  { id: 3, topic_no: 453, keywords: ["[Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3]"] },
];

let result = line1_x.map((elem) => {
  let strArr = elem.keywords[0].split("");
  strArr.shift();
  strArr.pop();

  let temp = strArr.join("").split(" ").join("").split(",");

  elem.keywords = temp;
  return elem;
});

console.log(result);
```